# A function that compares an integer to a list of integers and output the previous index's value if the number is greater than that index's value

Tags: python, list, comparison

I have a simple problem which I almost coded right but it then breaks after a certain number so it's unreliable.

Example python program:

```
quantity = 13
output = None

q_list = [1, 10, 25, 50, 100, 300, 500]
```

We need to loop through each value in q_list and compare it to quantity variable.

```
for i in range(len(q_list)):
    if quantity > q_list[i]:
        if i > 0:
            output = q_list[i-1]
    elif quantity == q_list[i]:
        output = quantity
```

However it does not always work. We need to check if i > 0 so that there is not chance we end up with. q_list[-n] where -n is some negative number which will in effect go to end of the list.

Example of expect output

```
When quantity= 5
    output = 1
When quantity = 11
    output = 10
When quantity = 1
    output = 1
when quantity = 10
    output = 10
When quantity = 505
    output = 500
```

You get the idea

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: it is unclear to me what this code is supposed to do, and what isn't working. Can you please explain what the expected output is (and the logic for arriving at it), and what the current output is?

Comment: I think they're looking for `bisect.bisect` or `bisect.bisect_left`

Comment: `Q_list = [1, 10, 25, 50, 100, 300, 500]` or `q_list` ???

Comment: You can use `range(1, len(q_list))` to make sure i-1 is not lesser than 0... can you add one or two examples of input, desired output and actual output? In particular for the "unreliable" cases.

Comment: I figured it out. Problem not the best way, but at least it works. See above

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem:

```
def get_nearest_highest_quantity(val, val_list):
    output = None

    for i in range(len(val_list)):

        # print("Checking: " + str(q) + " against: " + str(q_list[i]))

        if val > int(val_list[i]):
            if not i + 1 > len(val_list) - 1:
                if val < int(val_list[i + 1]):
                    output = val_list[i]
                    break
                else:
                    output = val_list[i + 1]
        elif val == val_list[i]:
            output = val
            break
        else:
            output = 0

    return output
```